# Inline script rendered as text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, inline-code

I have DOM objects given as an HTML string and are inserted into an HTML page by AJAX with the jQuery method `replaceWith()`. The HTML string includes a `<div>` element and an inline `<script>` that works on it, and the jQuery command is like the following:

```
$('#foo').replaceWith('<div>Some Content</div><script>someJavaScriptFunction();</script>');
```

After this AJAX is executed, the `<div>` element is rendered correctly, and the script inside the `<script>` is working, but in addition to that, the content of the inline `<script>` is rendered verbatim on the page. Why is this happening? How can I avoid this? When I see the corresponding part on Chrome developers tools, the inline script appears only once (which is what I intended).

Comment: can you try changing `'</script>'` to `'</scr'+'ipt>'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` forward slash of closing `script` tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5j5wn/)**

```
$('#foo').replaceWith('<div>Some Content</div><script>someJavaScriptFunction()<\/script>');
```